# How to root LAVA Iris Atom2 which runs Android 5.1

Tags: rooting, root-access

Can anyone help me to root my Lava Iris atom2 which runs android 5.1 OS,
I had tried almost available softwares like kingoroot , iroot , masterroot, towelroot. But Nothing works.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://d.kingoapp.com/default/KingoRoot.apk
Take easy root lava atom 2 5.1

Comment: Instead of just giving a link, could you please [edit] your answer and include at least a short summary of how it works? I assume it is a one-click solution and should hence be clear, but I'm not sure ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingo_Root) e.g. speaks of "Free Windows utility", and our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) also says "Windows PC required"). Also, are there any risks using this? Side-Effects?